# PostgreSQL copy row in a table with generated column

Tags: postgresql

Let's say I have a table with generated column.

```
CREATE TABLE foo (x int, y int, z int GENERATED ALWAYS AS (x + y) STORED);
INSERT INTO foo (x, y) VALUES (1, 1);
```

Is it possible to do something like this, but somehow omitting the generated column?

```
INSERT INTO foo SELECT * FROM foo;
```

I don't want to specify all the column names, because I want the insert to work even if new columns are added to the table.

I couldn't find any clever solution. [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/148908/is-there-a-way-to-clone-a-row-in-a-maintainable-way-with-postgresql) provides some idea, but I don't know whether it could be adapted. The only way I could think of is to set `z` value in before trigger instead of using generated column. Are there any recommendations in this area?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend in almost all cases to avoid using implicit columns. Specify the columns you want in both the INSERT and the SELECT:

```
INSERT INTO foo (x, y) SELECT x, y FROM foo;
```

Being explicit is a good thing in programming.

> *All things being equal, the simplest solution tends to be the best one.*

Comment: Yes, but in this case it won't work after adding/removing columns. Are there any risks in using `*` if this is select/insert from/to the same table.

Comment: That won't work, because a missing column list of INSERT is always implicitly means all the columns. But you can't insert a value into a generated column. You will have to specify the columns omitting the generated column, and if you ever add or remove columns, you will have to update your code.